# Convert SQL Stored Procedure to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm have a stored procedure that was written in SQL server. Since then I've migrated to MySQL and I'm having trouble with the syntax differences in this program. Can anyone help me? I admit this was working in SQL server and I've since started trying to convert it to MYSQL...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE POPPER

    (out StartDate datetime , 
    out EndDate datetime , 
    out USER CHAR(50) ,
    out PLACE Decimal(10,0),
    out PERIODPLAN Decimal(4,0), 
    out PERIOD Decimal(10,0) ,
    out BASE Decimal(6,2))


BEGIN


DELETE From DATES.PERIODFULL
WHERE
PERHOTID = PLACE AND
PERID = PERIOD AND
PERYEAR = PERIODPLAN;


DELETE From DATES.PERIODFULL
WHERE
PERDTE is NULL; 

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT StartDate AS myDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_ADD(myDate, INTERVAL 1 day) as myDate
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATE_ADD(myDate, INTERVAL 1 day) <=  EndDate
)

Insert into DATES.PERIODFULL
(USR1, PERHOTID, PERYEAR, PERID, PERDTE, PERBAS)
SELECT USER, PLACE, PERIODPLAN, PERIOD, myDate, BASE
FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

END
```

Comment: What is the actual question here? You have provided a non working code example with no explanation of what is not working. We might be able to help but you have to provide some kind of detail.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 doesn't support common table expressions (`WITH`). It looks like it will work if you rewrite it literally (which may mean you can't use recursion). CTEs are coming in the next version of MySQL.

Comment: Thanks Brian, do you have any ideas on how I would re-write it without recursion? I feel completely lost right now

Comment: Sorry Sean, to clarify, when I try to compile this code after the null; it says that it expects an end. Obviously I don't want to end there. If I do put an End the error then moves down to various places in the WITH statement, and also the recursion. I think this is because of what Brian mentioned. My real difficulty is how to re-write this in MySQL as I'm more familiar with SQL server

Comment: This code never worked in SQL Server.

Comment: No Gordon, this is the butchered version that I am trying to get working in MySQL. The original worked in SQL server... This is as far as I've got in getting it into MySQL and yes, it fails, hence I'm here asking for help.